# What is the significance of type signatures that are similar to definition?

Tags: dependent-type, idris

I realized that if I were to create a `swap` function in Idris, its type signature is almost exactly the same as its definition

```
swap : (a, b) -> (b, a)
swap (x, y) = (y, x)
```

Are there any implications or significance to this with regards to dependent typing?

For example, can I define some type/value agnostic swap and use it for both definitions here? Is there a special name for this parallelism?

Comment: I doubt that there's any significance. The reason that they are similar is because pairs are a type of [product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type). To form the product of two types `A` and `B` (i.e. to create a pair of the type `A * B`) you need two values `a : A` and `b : B`. This has nothing to do with dependent types.

Comment: You can probably express this kind of stuff using [very/insanely dependent types](https://github.com/UlfNorell/insane). But that's irrelevant in your case, since `(a, b)` and `(x, y)` have the same syntax, but are completely different things: `(a, b)` is a type, while `(x, y)` is a value. [Here](http://lpaste.net/145160) is a better example of repetition at the type level. I wonder whether there is a language that can express `default : ∀ {n} {A : Set} {C : Fin n -> Set} -> A -> ((i : Fin n) -> C i) -> ∀ m -> default A C m`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has any significance to dependent typing. Your function is already fully polymorphic (i.e. agnostic). I am unaware of a term for type-level between symmetric with term level syntax.